# using 'th' when writing date in British English

Tags: british-english, dates

Which format is more correct when writing date in UK?

"5 January 2019" or "5**th** January 2019" and why? Should I use "th" at the end? What is the best way to write it?

Comment: Neither is 'more correct'.

Comment: January 5(th) 2022 / 5(th) January 2022 with or without the suffix *th* there's no difference.

Comment: In the British press, rarely to never do I see an 'st', 'nd', 'rd', or 'th' after the numbered day in a date. It's written simply as '5 January 2019', to use your example. Now, when people read that aloud, they will very often say the 'th' or whatever, though. Say a sentence were, for example, 'The fete was held on 5 January 2019.' How one would likely read that sentence aloud would be, 'The fete was held on the fifth of January in twenty-nineteen,' or some other permutation thereof. How dates are styled in writing is different to how they're read aloud or even interpreted silently.